# Rails how to render partial with data form database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

i have a view called `week.haml` and a controller action called `def week` in which I get all my todos for this week. I want to render a partial called `_events.haml` inside `week.haml` which displays all events that week.

I did it like this:

inside `week.haml`:

```
= render partial: 'events`
```

inside `_events.haml`

```
%p= 'Events this week:'

@events.each do |event|
# stuff to show events
end
```

inside the todo controller:

```
def events
  @events = Event.where(some query)
end
```

But i always get the error message `@events not defined`. How can i load events into the event partial? and i don't want to do it inside `def week` if possible...

I also created a route:

```
resources :todo do
  get 'events', action: :events, as: :events
end
```

The `week.haml` file works fine, just the partial doesn't work.

Comment: ```= render partial: 'events', events: @events``` maybe? and then remove the @ in the partial

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice to use instance variables in partials, pass locals instead. Instance variables are for views

In your `week` view

```
= render partial: 'events`, events: week.events
```

And in partial `_events`

```rb
events.each do |event|
  # stuff to show events
end
```

Comment: It is bad practice, but it would have worked. Alas, they are loading `@events` in a wrong action (`def events`, not `def week`)

Comment: Yep, like instance variables inside view helpers :)

Comment: hey now, don't call me out like that!

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the controller action `week`, you'll need to get the events there or share `@events` between the different controller actions. If you're in the same scope (same controller in this case), you could create a private method for getting data that's similar between different views.

```rb
class TodoController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_events, only: [:week, :events]

  def week
    # Stuff for the week view
  end

  def events
    # Stuff for the events view
  end

  private
  
  def get_events
    @events = Event.where(...)
  end
end
```

In this example, the `@events` variable is available for both actions `week` and `events`. The `before_action` at the top runs `get_events` to load the `@events` variable before executing any other code in the controller action. Since it's an instance variable, it can be shared between different methods in the same class. Calling `get_events` at the top of both `week` and `events` would achieve the same result, but a `before_action` is usually cleaner IMO.

And just to be clear, all of this is assuming that you have separate views `events.haml` and `week.haml`. If not, creating a route and a controller method with the name of the partial does nothing. Just load the events in the `week` controller action and you're good to go! You could essentially think of a controller method as corresponding to a single view (of the same name usually), and a partial is just an extension of that view (and any other views that use the same partial). You load any data you might need for the view or any of its partials in the controller action, and then share whatever's needed with the partial. Instance variables (starting with "@") are shared automatically, but anything else you would need to pass to the partial explicitly.

Partials are meant for things you need to render multiple times (and/or in multiple places). [The Rails docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) have a pretty thorough section about them. If you're only rendering events for a single week in `week.haml`, you probably don't even need the partial, unless you want to use it in other views.

Comment: In the real code, it probably wouldn't make sense to reuse the query (`get_events`) between `week` and `events`. Sounds like `events` could display events from all weeks. But otherwise, this answer is great.